# why in my code second "for" in function loop only once

Tags: c, function, for-loop, nested-loops

i wrote this nested "for" program but second loop only work once and print one row of "x"

```
#include <stdio.h>

void draw_box(int , int);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    draw_box(8 , 35);
    return 0;
}

void draw_box(int row , int column)
{
    for(;row>0;row--)
    {
        for(;column>0;column--)
            printf("X");

      printf("\n");      
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `column`?

Comment: Use local variable like `for( int i = column; i > 0; i--)`

Comment: because 'column' is ==0 after the inner looping has been performed once.  Follow the comment of: @Himanshu, to correct the problem.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  For instance, the parameter `argc` and the parameter `argv` are not used.  TO fix those two problems, use the alternate valid signature for `main()`  I.E. `int main( void )`

Answer (score 9):

The second loop functions only once because it runs the value of `column` into zero, and never resets it back to the original value passed in as a parameter:

```
for(;row>0;row--) {
    int origColumn = column; // Save the value
    for(;column>0;column--)
        printf("X");
    column = origColumn;     // Restore the value
    printf("\n");      
}
```

This illustrates why one should be very careful when modifying values passed to your function as parameters. Your function would be as easy to write and easier to read with loop variables:

```
for(int r = 0 ; r != row ; r++) {
    for(int c = 0 ; c != column ; c++)
        printf("X");
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: This illustrates why input-only parameters should always be `const`. Well practically always, excluding reference counting types of course.

Comment: then why its not happening to 'row' variable

Comment: @Sina.Mh Because it is in the outer loop, so you need to run it down to zero only once. In contrast, `column` needs to be run to zero multiple times.

Comment: @Sina.Mh, first `for` loop have to run only once i.e 8 to 0. but inner loop have to work again and again for every single value of outer loop.

Comment: @Sina.Mh it's typically a useful case to discover debugger. with a debugger you can run your program step by step and see evolution of your variables. Debugger, in addition to being an indispensable tool to develop, is also a really good tools to learn programming.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that, your second loop iterates to zero and was never rest to its original value. You can either assign the value to a temporary variable and use that for iteration, and at the closing of the second "for" loop, set the temp value back to the default value **OR** You could change the for loop structure by assigning a variable j=0, and iterating it over and over again until it does not satisfy the condition j

The first for loop does not face this problem because, when you enter the firs for loop, the second for loop is executed "column" number of times before the control goes back to the first for loop.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using nested for loops

```
for(;row>0;row--)
{
    for(;column>0;column--)
        printf("X");     
}
```

For each value of  *row* , you are iterating through entire *column*.
So, X is printed the number of column times.
But value of *column* is reduced to **zero** each time you iterate through **outer loop**.

**For clarification consider inner loop :**
If value of *column* is 5,
*X* is printed and the value of *column* reduces to 4.
 Similarly, X will be printed 5 times and at that moment, value of *column* reduces to **zero**

Now, for the second iteration of **outer loop**, value of *column* remains **zero** and it will not pass the inner loop condition. Thus your pointer will not move inside the second loop to print *X* .

**How to overcome this :** Use loop-variable.
Now every time you iterate through  inner loop, value of *loop-variable* will be reduced and not of *column*.
So, while iterating through through **outer loop** second time, value of *loop-variable* will be restored to value of *column* and then *X* could be printed *column* number of times(in this case 5).

**Solution :**

```
for(i = 0; i < row; i++){           //Good habit to start from 0, as it is
    for(j = 0; j < column; j++){   //useful when you are working with matrix
        printf("X");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```